# How to check geographical variation/self citation in the citing articles on Google Scholar?

Tags: citations, google-scholar, bibliometrics

In my department, I have been assigned to find geographical variation and self-citation in the citing articles of some research papers. On Google Scholar, manually it is very difficult to check citations for every research paper. For example, one of the research article has 650 citations, it would be a laborious task to check every citing article for geographical variation and self-citations.

Is there any tool which classifies citing articles based on their geographical variation and self-citations?

Comment: Do you have access to Web of Science or Scopus?

Answer (score 3):

Many universities subscribe to Scopus. Scopus make it much easier to identify self-citations. It also makes it  easier to identify articles that belong to a given research and export citation of these articles for analysis.  So you might want to check that out.

I think scopus will identify how many citations to a given author are self-citations.

Identifying more complex features such as geographical patterns is likely to involve more work. It's unclear even what is meant by geographical pattern. I can imagine that each author could be assigned to a country based on their current institutional affiliation. And each paper could then be assigned to one or more geographical locations based on the affiliation of the authors of the paper.

However, this would probably involve a lot of manual work. Perhaps there are scripts that could automate this. Scopus does have the affiliation of many authors.